# SQL Server 2012 / Add row_number over two queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, union, row-number

I have a question about adding a row number over 2 queries.

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    'telxm001001' AS Node, 
    '1' AS [Speed Dialing], 
    '0' AS [Spd DI Numbers by Range], 
    NULL as 'Speed Dialing No.',  
    REPLACE(TelefonGeschaeft, '+', '00') AS [Call Number], 
    Nachname AS [Directory Name], 
    Vorname AS [Directory First Name]
FROM
    dbo.MaData
WHERE        
    (TelefonGeschaeft LIKE '+%')

UNION ALL

SELECT       
    'telxm001001' AS Node, 
    '1' AS [Speed Dialing], 
    '0' AS [Spd DI Numbers by Range], 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Nachname) AS 'Speed Dialing No.',    
    REPLACE(MobiltelefonGeschaeft, '+', '00') AS [Call Number], 
    Nachname AS [Directory Name], 
    Vorname AS [Directory First Name]
FROM
    dbo.MaData
WHERE        
    (MobiltelefonGeschaeft LIKE '+%')
```

I have a SQL Server table with 1400 entries. The 2 queries brings me the right results but the row numbers are not correct because the numerations Begins at 1 when the second query starts. So in my query result i have a numeration from 1 to 680 and then the numeration Begins at 1 when the second query starts. Is there a way to add a row numbering after the two queries finished so the numeration is from 1 to 1400?

Best regards
switzly

Answer (score 0):

Apply a ROW_NUMBER ordering over a derived query; supply a discriminator (e.g. queryOrder) through the individual queries to keep the relevant results grouped.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY queryOrder, [Directory Name]) AS number
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS queryOrder, [Directory Name] ..
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS queryOrder, [Directory Name] ..
) j
```

Answer (score 0):

Before jump into too techie in to this query, do you want to have the row number for both the queries?

If yes, why are you putting NULL in the first query?

If you want to have row number for both the queries, use it on both the queries.

Otherwise, try put them into another query as below:

```
select 
     ROW_NUMBER over ..., Node, [Speed Dialing], .... 
from 
     (<actual query here>) as temp1;
```

Comment: i want to have the row number over query 1 and 2 and not separated as it is in my actual query.